# What is a better way for this solution - Different Database for saving user data in multi tenant rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apartment-gem

I have scenario for saving the information like name, address and other personal details of a user in a separate database so later the application admin operate on that data.
I'm using Apartment gem for multi tenancy.Other than separate database, Is there a way like blacklisting the table in public schema so the upcoming migration won't effect to other tenants.
only the public schema will have that table.
Any one faced a scenario like this before?
I'm looking for suggestion for this.Any help is appreciated.